# Get VirtualBox windows guest to use Linux host's /etc/hosts to resolve URLs

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox and want to test some sub-domain functionality locally.

The setup is:

**Host machine:**

- Linux Mint
- runs a local web server with a local copy of my app

**Guest machine:**

- Windows 7/8
- has Internet Explorer browser

**Internet:**

- my live version of the app

I wanted to test by using the Windows guest machine's IE browser to see my app, by using my app's live internet URL, but instead of going to the actual live version, having the browser redirected to the local version of the app.

Normally I have done accomplished this with editing `/etc/hosts`, which is currently configured to direct all calls the live URL, to the localhost.

But currently when I use the Windows guest's IE, it does not seem to be reading host machine's `/etc/hosts`, and is instead, going directly to the online, live website.

What's the fix for this?

Comment: To clarify, host machine is Linux Mint, VirtualBox guest machine is an unknown version of Windows with IE. And host machine/Linux Mint is running a web server right?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Windows is 7/8.

Comment: Wrong forum. This belongs to **Super User** as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @tink isn't testing of code still fair game.

Comment: @Cenoc : i guess perceptions may vary; but imho you're not testing your app, but the interaction between two OSes/platforms. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible for a VirtualBox guest to directly use host machine's `/etc/hosts`, however if we keep in mind your intended testing outcome:

1. Using VirtualBox Windows 7/8 guest machine's IE, open internet URL http://www.yourwebsite.com
2. Displays not the live online website but Linux Mint host machine's local server version

Then, one approach is to edit the VirtualBox Windows 7/8 guest machine's hosts file to redirect such requests to the VirtualBox IP address representing the Linux Mint host machine.

Here are the details, according to [How Do I Change My Hosts File](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/technical/how-do-i-change-my-hosts-file):

### Windows 7 guest machine

> Browse to Start > All Programs > Accessories.
>
> Right-click Notepad, and select Run as administrator.
>
> Click Continue on the UAC prompt.
>
> Click File > Open.
>
> Browse to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc.
>
> Change the file filter drop-down box from Text Documents (`*.txt`) to All Files (`*.*`).
>
> Select hosts, and click Open.
>
> Make the needed changes, ...  and close Notepad.
>
> Save when prompted.

### Windows 8

Same steps except for how you find Notepad.

### The needed changes

The needed change in `hosts`, for example if you want to redirect `www.yourwebsite.com`:

```
10.0.2.2 www.yourwebsite.com
```

Your changes should [take effect immediately](http://www.howtogeek.com/122404/how-to-block-websites-in-windows-8s-hosts-file/) so open IE browser to `http://www.yourwebsite.com` to test.

### Explanation

According to VirtualBox documentation, [NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) `...is the default networking mode in VirtualBox.`, and with NAT, [`the gateway is set to 10.0.2.2`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat)

Note that gateway = your host machine.

So for the guest to reach the host machine by IP, http://10.0.2.2 can be used. This can be tested in the guest machine, just open IE browser and type http://10.0.2.2

We then make use of the Windows hosts file to set custom host name resolutions, so whenever the guest reaches for http://www.yourwebsite.com it will redirect to 10.0.2.2, your Linux Mint host machine running the your local copy of web app.